# How do I give an autoresize function greater than 26?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

If you set a value greater than 26 for the `autoresize` function, an error will occur. `"Exception: Those columns are out of bounds."` How to fix it?

Comment: You can show the code of what have you tried?

Comment: Hi ! Please provide a sample of the code you are using so that we can see if there is any issue with it that you could not spot.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

You said you have `96` columns. Most likely, you are not referencing to the correct sheet. Because `26` is the default number of columns when you create a new sheet. Make sure you refer to the correct sheet. You can use `getSheetByName("Sheet1")` and replace `Sheet1` with the name of your sheet.

---

Just add more columns in the sheet or reduce that number

- you don't have `26` columns available in your sheet:

if you use [autoResizeColumn(columnPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeColumn(Integer)) make sure `columnPosition` exists in the sheet.

- you don't have `26` columns after the starting specified column:

if you use [autoResizeColumns(startColumn, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeColumns(Integer,Integer)) make sure you have `numColumns` **after** `startColumn`

Comment: marios I have 96 coloumn

Comment: @TipVisor can you specify which version of `autoResizeColumn` you are using? if you use the second one, do you have `startColumn + numColumns` columns available? See my updated answer. Most likely you are using the wrong sheet instead of the one with 96 columns

Comment: @TipVisor was that the issue ? I updated the answer .